# Excel-Custom Validation Formula

Tags: validation, excel-formula

I've figured out how to do this individually, but need help in combining for a custom formula.

I want a formula that requires the person to enter data that:
* must be numeric (ISNUMBERS);
* requires the manual data entry of eight characters;
* may start with a zero, and if it does, the zero should be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third requirement is a formatting issue not a data validation issue.

Format the cells as text.

Then the formula is:

```
=AND(LEN(A1)=8,ISNUMBER(--A1))
```